# Unable to connect to Mongo using mongoose.connect

Tags: node.js, mongoose

> **Error:** "MongoError: failed to connect to server [config.mongoUrl:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo
>   ENOTFOUND config.mongoUrl config.mongoUrl:27017]"

I am running Mac `osX` Yosemite version `10.10.5`
 My dependencies are listed below from the pkg.json file with their 
 versions

`MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10`

`DB version v3.2.10`

my folder structure is as follows for this:

```
-->src
 --> config
  |--> index.js
 --> middleware
  |--> index.js
 --> routes
  |--> index.js
 --> db.js
 --> index.js
```

in config/index.js the code is as follows:

```
export default {
   "port": 3000,
   "mongoUrl": 'mongodb://localhost:27017/some-api'
}
```

In db.js the code is as follows:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from './config';

export default callback => {
  let db = mongoose.connect('config.mongoUrl');
  callback(db);
}
```

I have tried replacing the localhost with 127.0.0.1
I have tried connecting directly instead of from config. I have tried using the only localhost without MongoDB. My dependencies are listed below. 
I have done this once before and it worked I am unsure why it does not work.

I apologize if this question seems redundant but I was unable to find a working answer here on the stack. Any help would be appreciated.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "eslint": "^3.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.6",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
```

Comment: Aside from the mistake of supplying a "string" as opposed to the correct object reference, your present usage is deprecated. In the context you are using it the `.connect()` here would return a `Promise` and not a callback or resolved reference to the database connection. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html. Version 4.6.6 is quite old and your project really should be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you're trying to connect 'config.mongoUrl' which is a string literal. Please remove '' and try again.

```
let db = mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
```

Comment: Thank you subaru710! It is the little things that always get me. I was staring at this for hours and just overlooked it. I appreciated you taking the time. Truly I do.

Comment: You're welcome Joseph:) If it works now, please accept this answer. thanks